# How to prevent overflow text in a text block?

Tags: windows-phone-7, scroll

I'm trying to make an ebook reader. I want each page to scroll sideways (like the Pivot viewer does) but I can't get out how to figure out how many words need to be added to the text box on a screen to before it starts overflowing (I don't want the user to scroll vertically).

Any tips?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `Scrollable TextBlock` which divide text into blocks of 2048px height. You can use their code to get text that will exactly fit into one page (800px, for example)

[Creating Scrollable TextBlock for WP7](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/09/08/creating-scrollable-textblock-for-wp7.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you call the  [`UIElement.Measure(Size)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.measure.aspx) method, then check the [`UIElement.DesiredSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.desiredsize.aspx) property, it will tell you the size of an element before it is rendered. You could add text, repeatedly measuring the rendered size.

However ... this will be pretty inefficient. It is much better if you can create a layout that performs what you require automatically.